# Add new elements to JSON array

Tags: json, jq

I have a config file that is like

```
[
  "ECSClusterName=cluster",
  "VPCID=vpc-xxxx",
  "ALBName=ALB"
]
```

And with `jq` (or something else bash-native), I'd like to add 2 values - `EnvType` and `KMSID` - (doesn't matter where in the config file) so that the end result would look like

```
[
  "EnvType=dev",
  "KMSID=xxxxx-yyyyyy-ffffff",
  "ECSClusterName=cluster",
  "VPCID=vpc-xxxx",
  "ALBName=ALB"
]
```

The closest I have been for one value is

```
cat config.json | jq '.[-1] += ", test=test"'
```

But that outputs

```
[
  "ECSClusterName=cluster",
  "VPCID=vpc-xxxx",
  "ALBName=ALB, test=test"
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put new `key=value` pairs into an array, and add that array to the original one.

```
$ jq '. + ["EnvType=dev", "KMSID=xxxxx-yyyyyy-ffffff"]' config.json
[
  "ECSClusterName=cluster",
  "VPCID=vpc-xxxx",
  "ALBName=ALB",
  "EnvType=dev",
  "KMSID=xxxxx-yyyyyy-ffffff"
]
```

Comment: Quick question though - not directly related. Do you know why my arg are not correctly interpreted? `jq --arg EnvType ${env} --arg KMSID ${kmsid} '. + ["EnvType=[$EnvType]", "KMSID=[$KMSID]"]' config.json`

Comment: @Mornor Unless you put them into string interpolation parens (like `"EnvType=[\($EnvType)]"`), variable names in strings are not parsed and expanded.